# Member function binding using boost

Tags: c++, boost, bind, member-functions

I'm trying to set up a system where GUI objects that derive from a GuiObject class can register a Serialiser and Deserialiser so that they can be serialised/deserialised to/from an XML file based solely on a class alias. For example:

```
class Button : public GuiObject
{
    // ...
};
```

`Button` might look like this in XML:

```
<button>
    [...]
</button>
```

So the idea is that the client code can register a serialiser and deserialiser for a `GuiObject` derivative, **using a placeholder for the object to call the function on**:

```
typedef boost::function<void(ticpp::Element*)> serialisation_function;

// ...

serialisation_function serialiserFunc(boost::bind(&Button::WriteElement, _1, _2));
GuiObjectXmlSerialiser buttonSerialiser("button", serialiserFunc);
guiObjectXmlFactory.registerSerialiser(buttonSerialiser);
```

`Button::WriteElement` looks like:

```
virtual void WriteElement(ticpp::Element* element) const;
```

GuiObjectXmlSerialiser.h:

```
typedef boost::function<void(ticpp::Element*)> serialisation_function;

// Serialises a GuiObject via a creation and serialisation function, storing
// a class name to differentiate it between others.
class GuiObjectXmlSerialiser
{
public:
    GuiObjectXmlSerialiser(const std::string& class_alias,
        serialisation_function serialisation_func);

    void serialise(gui_object_ptr object, ticpp::Element* element);
private:
    std::string class_alias;
    serialisation_function serialisation_func;
};
```

GuiObjectXmlSerialiser.cpp:

```
GuiObjectXmlSerialiser::GuiObjectXmlSerialiser(const std::string& class_alias,
serialisation_function serialisation_func)
: class_alias(class_alias)
, serialisation_func(serialisation_func)
{
}

void GuiObjectXmlSerialiser::serialise(gui_object_ptr object, ticpp::Element* element)
{
    serialisation_func(object, element);
}
```

Currently, I'm getting this error at the `serialisation_func(object, element);` line:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
```

So **I'd like to know how to delay passing in the object to call the member function on, specifying the object to use at the same time as calling the function.** I've been staring at this for a while now to no avail.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two errors:

First you define a function that takes a single argument, but you try to call it with two arguments:

```
// Single argument of type ticpp::Element*
typedef boost::function<void(ticpp::Element*)> serialisation_function;
// Call with two arguments:
serialisation_func(object, element); 

// You probably meant:
typedef boost::function<void(gui_object_ptr, ticpp::Element*)> serialisation_function;
```

Second, you don't take into account that your function is a member function. That means it's actually taking a third parameter, `this` (in first position). You should check whether this should be a member function or not, but I think there's a mistake in your understanding.

```
// From your code I am not sure what [serial_instance] should be.
serialisation_function serialiserFunc(boost::bind(&Button::WriteElement, [serial_instance] , _1, _2));
```

Comment: When I called the code with two parameters, it was because I was trying to clarify that I wanted to bind the object to call the function on at that point in the code, not at creation of the `function` as in your example.

The `_1` (during construction of the `serialisation_function`) is supposed to be the object to call the member function on. So what I'd like to know is how to delay binding the object until the function is called. I apologise, as looking back, my question could have been a bit clearer.

Comment: Sounds dangerous with a virtual function, but you can try the following, boost docs say it's working. First have your function take two parameters `typedef boost::function<void(gui_object_ptr, ticpp::Element*)> serialisation_function;` then bind it without doing anything special: `serialisation_function serialiserFunc(&Button::WriteElement);`. I didn't test sorry, no time for that now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate copy of class-object, for wich you want to call binding, smth like:

```
Button* btn = new Button();
serialisation_function serialiserFunc(boost::bind(&Button::WriteElement, btn, _1, _2));
```

also you can use `this` pointer, if you want to create binding for this class object copy

Comment: My question is - how would I delay indicating which object I want to call the function on?

Comment: As in my example, you pass second parameter in boost::bind pointer to copy of class object.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding my question - please see J.N.'s last comment to clarify what I'm trying to do.